# Polygon vertices in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I make the vertices of a polygon in libgdx?
I am trying to make a pentagon for collision detection and I am kind of confused about how the vertices part is done, until now I used rectangle to achieve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make several polygons since a pentagon is a convex shape and not easy to compute if a point is within the shape.

To create a shape with the `Polygon` class you specify the vertices with a float array. In sequence, you specify the x and y positions. Since `Polygon` is a 2D shape in Libgdx the Z axis is not needed.

Below is a polygon for a triangle shape, create your pentagon like this from multiple polygons and use `Intersector` to test the polygon vs various other geometry like lines and points. Note, `Intersector` does contain method `overlapConvexPolygon` but I am pretty sure that gives true for something in between the points of your pentagon.

```
new Polygon(new Array[
0, 0,
10, 0,
5, 10
]);
```